# Pinging CS Servers

Tags: php, udp

This has been bothering me for awhile, can some one show me how to ping a counter strike server.

I just want to ping the server and see if it is online, thats all.

I found many small snippets online that were using fsock and UDP to do this but none of them actually did the job i wanted it to do.

Most of the ones i found were showing offline servers as online.

I would really really appreciate if some one could provide me with this useful information (code).

Thank you in advance ^_^

Answer (score 1):

you can't just ping the server since it uses UDP instead of normal TCP, so in order to check it's status you need to "query" the server, you can find information about what command you can send to CS servers here: http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries#A2A_PING

Anyway the following code (PHP) can be used to check CS server status.

`

`  
        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
        socket_connect($socket, "cs.somesv.com", 27015);

```
    socket_write($socket, "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x69");

    if (@socket_read($socket, 5) == "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x6A") {
        echo '<FONT COLOR=lime>Online</FONT>';
    } else {
        echo '<FONT COLOR=red>Offline</FONT>';
    }

    socket_close($socket);
?>`
```

Bah! this code blocks don't really work fine! :(

Anyway, I use this code everyday for my server, hope it works fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two choices off the top of my head:

**fsockopen**:

http://www.phptoys.com/e107_plugins/content/content.php?content.41

**Net_Ping Pear package**:

http://www.codediesel.com/php/ping-a-server-using-php/

Using IP of the CS server.

Comment: Thanks, the first link i found already but it doesn't do the job.

The second link is something like what i need - but it requires alot of things that i would have only if i had root access.

Alot of the stuff it requires is disabled on my server (i.e exec() function).

Answer (score 0):

Get ClanManager and it has modules to check status of CS server.

This is the file with examples talking with CS servers,

http://clanmanager.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/clanmanager/ocm/server/counterstrike.inc?revision=1.3&view=markup

Comment: Thanks for the link - the code look on that class looks pretty outdated and not what i was interested in.

I don't want to Query the Server for its information, i just need ping it to Only verify that it's online and alive.

http://gameq.sourceforge.net is better than the above one, if i had to choose though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do what's known as a TCP ping.  Basically, you just connect then disconnect without any communication.  If the connection succeeds, you know the server is up, if it fails it's down.  When I say server I mean the program you're interested in, not the physical server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is PHP function to check if CS server is online:

```
function isCsServerOnline($server, $port = 27015)
{
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);

    // timeout 1.5 seconds
    $timeout = array('sec' => 1, 'usec' => 500000);
    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, $timeout);
    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, $timeout);

    @socket_connect($socket, $server, $port);
    @socket_write($socket, "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x69");

    $isOnline = @socket_read($socket, 5) == "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x6A";
    @socket_close($socket);

    return $isOnline;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
$server = 'some.cs.server';
$port = 27015;

$isOnline = isCsServerOnline($server, $port);
echo $isOnline ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
```